# inject.preload.js failing to load a file in chrome from my dev environment

Tags: google-chrome, adblock

I use google chrome for my php/js development.

today I started to see a file that is failing to load.

file name is always different

```
Request URL: blob:http://random.homestead.test/4d9f984b-b8f8-4e77-97cb-4fcfd8ace348
```

network page says that initiator is `inject.preload.js:373`

if I open this file, the first line says

```
/*
 *This file is part of Adblock Plus <https://adblockplus.org/>,
```

But I have Adblock Plus disabled. I noticed that file is being loaded with success occasionally. And also noticed that this file is only requested when I have AdBlock (not AdblockPlus) active. If I have AdBlock disabled - no problem. but even if I exclude my dev site from adblock - the file download is still failing.

My question is: **How can I get rid of this red line in my console log and network without entirely deactivating adblock?**

I tried it on stackoverflow.com and I see the same file `inject.preload.js` loading same randomly named file and succeeding. the file header says:

```
/*
* Frame context wrapper
*
* For some edge-cases Chrome will not run content scripts inside of frames.
* Website have started to abuse this fact to access unwrapped APIs via a
* frame's contentWindow (#4586, 5207). Therefore until Chrome runs content
* scripts consistently for all frames we must take care to (re)inject our
* wrappers when the contentWindow is accessed.
*/
```

it started today on 14 of June 2018

Comment: I'm seeing this on every site, not just local dev

Comment: try ublock origin, it works flawlessly and it's open source.

Comment: Getting those errors on almost every site now. Development or not…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comment https://issues.adblockplus.org/ticket/6744#comment:17 , you can find a link to build list https://downloads.adblockplus.org/devbuilds/adblockpluschrome/, install the development version "Adblock Plus for Google Chrome and Opera 3.1.0.2069" and the error won't display anymore

[image: build list]

**updated**

On 2018.7.17 the new verison with bug fixed is released on chrome webstore. So this issue is automatically resolved.

Answer (score 68):

Looks like it is officially broken. The issue is ticketed at https://issues.adblockplus.org/ticket/6744

I tried to debug and find the exact cause, but the issue seems to be elsewhere.
The JS code debugged (inject.preload.js at line 373)

```
document.documentElement.appendChild(script); // here, script.src is indeed a valid script
document.documentElement.removeChild(script);
URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

The `script`'s src attribute targets a valid blob JS which is alive when this line is called!

Comment: Thank you. It is working all right today. Even though ticket still in reviewing stage.  I'm using Chrome 67. It is strange.

Comment: Still getting the same error posted by @combomatrix with latest version of ABP and Chrome 67

Comment: Same here on Chrome 67!

Comment: What I find interesting is, I don't have AdBlockPlus installed at all, and I get this error (inject.preload.js:373). Same as OP though, if I disable AdBlock (which is apparently unrelated to AdBlockPlus) the error goes away.

As with the OP, disabling it for my dev domain also doesn't remove the error (but I get a nice green thumbs up icon in browser toolbar)

Answer (score 11):

the ticket is on review and they working on it.
Now you can add the entire test site to your trusted sites

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I installed an older version of Chrome and I solved the problem.
https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php

Comment: Problem was solved by itself on the next day for me even with latest version of Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

If you have any adBlocker then remove or pause for that specific page adBlocker, it worked for me i had the same issue with JavaScript Application when fetching data from Firestore.